swiftui application how to implement swipe to select items in lazyvgrid
I want to implement a function: swipe to select multiple griditems, just like the functionality in FileManager of IOS:

an item with a Text("Hello") and a Text("World") are displayed in the lazyvgrid of scrollview
swipe on the Text("Hello"), the items passed through are selected and scrollview does not response to scroll, while scrollview will scroll automatically when user remains finger on the 1st or lastest griditem
swipe on the file name, scrollview is responsed to scroll normally

.gesture attached in the griditem and a timer fired to scroll item can achieve the requirements except that I find the griditem will be reused while scrolling which means that .gesture's onChange and onEnd will not called any more, is there any way to fix the problem? Thanks a lot.
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    let dispWidth = CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 9 / 10)
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200, maximum: dispWidth), alignment: .trailing)], spacing: 10) {                            ForEach(0..<itemsCount, id: \.self) { index in
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Hello \(index):")
                                        .frame(width: 100)
                                        .border(.blue, width: isItemSelected(index: index) ? 1 : 0)
                                        .overlay {
                                            GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
                                                let frame = geometry.frame(in: .named(containerSpace))
                                                itemsRect.content[index] = frame
                                                return Color.clear
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .gesture(dragSelect(proxy: proxy, geometry: geometry))
                                    Text("World No# \(index)")
                                        .frame(width: 200)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { proxy  -> Color in
                        scrollviewHeight = proxy.size.height
                        return Color.clear
                    }
                 }
                .coordinateSpace(name: containerSpace)
}

